# cakephp Managing Plugin Views how to determine paths

Tags: cakephp, plugins, path, routes, view

I have a plugin installed that has its own layout overrides for different controllers.  However I'm having trouble understanding the mechanism for modifying the paths.

In the plug-in controller if I tell it to use my layout

```
$this->layout = 'default_dashboard';
```

Which is in app/Views/Layout and references an image in app/webroot/default_images.

All the relative links work fine to default_images when I do this, but would like to use some of the Plugin template overides for other actions.

However if I modify the default.cpt file to include some of the images, like say a logo that is used in default_dashboard.ctp.  It is unable to map to the same image location.
For example in default.ctp:

```
echo $this->Html->image('default_images/logo.png',array('alt' =>
 'Logo','width'=>'284','height'=>'82'));
```

produces a path to /img/default_images/logo.png.  The Plugin is configured to use the /img location, whereas I want to direct to /default_images in this case.  I could make this ../default_images/logo.png, but this isn't very clean.

In addition I have js and css which is having a similar problem.  Can someone please explain the mechanism for using a site-wide default.ctp so that it works with inherited plugin templates?

From hard coding the links into the template not using the Html Helper, I see that the browser's relative path is confused because of the routing.  For example the first one works with the root specified, the second doesn't.

```
    <img src="/default_images/logo.png" alt="works" width='284' height='82'>
    <img src="default_images/logo.png" alt="lost" width='284' height='82'>
```

What's the best way to make sure that the Plugin layouts and non-plugin layouts can all find the correct path to /default_images ?

Comment: It is always best to use `/` as root and relative paths to this root: `image('/dir_in_root/logo.png')`. That will work from whatever location you are referring to it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that in the Html helper if I put in /default_images it wouldn't try to route to /img/default_images.

Comment: that is the point if you use those root-relative urls. It will assume you want to specify the complete path. Using `some_dir` it will place it relative to the "/img" folder (thus as subfolder to it).

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know it was smart enough to not try to route it to its own absolute structure for the plugin.../img/some_dir

Comment: Also, take a look at the Cake constants, they can help make your code clearer.  e.g. `IMAGES` points to the default image directory. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps that you can follow to resolve relative path problem:

1. Create a file `abc_constants.php` in `app\Config` folder.
2. Include the file in `app\Config\bootstrap.php`

   `require_once(abc_constants.php);`
3. abc_constants.php should contain:

   ```
   define('HTTP_HOST', "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');
   define('SITE_URL', HTTP_HOST.'your_app_name/');
   define('IMAGE_HTTP_PATH', SITE_URL.'app/webroot/default_images/');
   ```
4. Use these constants in your view file accordingly.

   ```
   <?php echo $this->Html->image(IMAGE_HTTP_PATH.'logo.png',array('alt' => 'Logo','width'=>'284','height'=>'82'));
   ```

It looks a bit lengthy process at first time, but once implemented, you can use these constants in Ajax calls in view files, controller's code etc.